# unrecognized selector on cast object ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, casting, selector

So I have an object, `UIView *_baseView`, and I cast that object as a subclass of that object.

```
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)_baseView;
```

This is what GPUImageView Class looks like:

```
@interface GPUImageView : UIView <GPUImageInput>
{
    GPUImageRotationMode inputRotation;
}
```

And this is what GPUImageInput Class looks like:

```
@protocol GPUImageInput <NSObject>
- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;
- (void)setInputFramebuffer:(GPUImageFramebuffer *)newInputFramebuffer atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;
- (NSInteger)nextAvailableTextureIndex;
- (void)setInputSize:(CGSize)newSize atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;
- (void)setInputRotation:(GPUImageRotationMode)newInputRotation atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex;
- (CGSize)maximumOutputSize;
- (void)endProcessing;
- (BOOL)shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget;
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (BOOL)wantsMonochromeInput;
- (void)setCurrentlyReceivingMonochromeInput:(BOOL)newValue;
@end
```

Now when I call `[filterView nextAvailableTextureIndex];` I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView nextAvailableTextureIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x135547260'
```

I know _baseView is not a GPUImageView and doesn't have the selector, but this is how it is done in the example application that seems to build fine. Is there a reason why a cast would work in some cases and not in others?

Comment: You need to look at the example further. You must be missing a step. Look at how `_baseView` is created. You are getting a plain old `UIView` but the example seems to be creating an actual `GPUImageView`.

Comment: The example sets filterView by casting self.view in the UIViewController.  `GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;`

Comment: And look at how `self.view` is set. Perhaps the `loadView` method is implemented to make the view controllers main view a `GPUImageView`.

Comment: Casting a pointer type in Objective-C has no effect at runtime; it's simply a way of providing additional type information at compile time. If the type information provided by a cast is incorrect, the result is often a runtime exception such as the one you're seeing.

Comment: I am setting _baseView from self.view and passing that to the framework. Here is a link to the example https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/examples/iOS/SimpleVideoFilter/SimpleVideoFilter/SimpleVideoFilterViewController.m

Comment: So the view controller is created from a xib. And the xib is setup such that the view controller's main view is a `GPUImageView`. Perhaps you didn't do that.